# Spock : Verify Interaction Not working -- Too few Invocations

Tags: spock

I have a very simple class as shown

```java
class MyClass {

  public static String getName(String input)
  {
    return toUpperCase(input);
  }

  public static String toUpperCase(String name)
  {
    return name.toUpperCase();
  }    
}
```

To test the above I have written a Test Case using Spock FW as shown below:

```java
class MyClassTest extends  Specification{
  def 'check uppercase scnario'() {

    given:
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    when:
    myClass.getName("test")

    then: ""
    1*myClass.toUpperCase("test");
  }   
}
```

But when I run this I see 0 Interactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot verify interactions on static Java methods. Just make your methods non-static. Besides, in the `given:` block, you are instantiating the class, so I guess you want to use instance methods anyway.

```java
class MyClass {
  public String getName(String input) {
    return toUpperCase(input);
  }

  public String toUpperCase(String name) {
    return name.toUpperCase();
  }    
}
```

Furthermore, if you wish to verify interactions on self-invocation calls, a `Mock()` is not what you need. Instead, simply use a `Spy()`:

```java
class MyClassTest extends Specification {
  def 'check uppercase scnario'() {
    given:
    MyClass myClass = Spy()

    when:
    myClass.getName("test")

    then:
    1 * myClass.toUpperCase("test");
  }   
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJxlkL8OwiAQh_c-xcVF6mDiqnFy1qX6AHieldhSAod_Ynx3KULT6ATc78vH3WEjnYPtcxPPVwFg_LFRCBVbpWuoiXeyJZGeShvPZeQALLG3Grg7GEN2Ix2Jb74K8bv4c43BVNLB_aPrS_Mx-tX1RBGkOG54T46BHkz65KAyhOqsULLqdHSe6AxTvBBewfc6DDpwqKVV3VTkf2t1I72M17yHNp3rIH2Ksojh_ZKxFM_zciYc-pgkjAdsAbMBHQ-U8DxWmOoD8iV66A).